# Losing the session after the Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been using session variables in my asp.net application for passing the next property:

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool IsModificationMode
{
    get
    {
        return (bool)Session["ModificationMode"];
    }
    set { Session["ModificationMode"] = value; }
}
```

In the PageLoad, I set it's value.

Now after the Postback, I am losing it's value having a a NullReferenceException

Comment: Can you show the code of your postback where you set the value?

Comment: show the code when you set the property IsModificationMode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I upvoted [@stacknewbee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418225/stacknewbee) because I agree with his idea of the application pool self-recycling. As a solution, try uncoupling the session state from the w3wp.exe process by changing the web.config entry from InProc to StateServer:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" timeout="30"/>
```

Keep in mind that the server service ASP.Net State Server must be started.

Answer (score 4):

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="Session" />
            <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
            <remove name="ScriptModule" />
```

If after you've done the above you still have no joy you need to add the session state module...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Dom. Can you provide some more context and explanation as to what your answer does, and how it improves on the other answers posted 2+ years ago. Thanks.

Comment: @Deanna, +1, beat me to the review by 16 seconds. Though I might add "other _accepted_ answers".

Answer (score 1):

The issue is may be because of,
1. You are either clearing the session somewhere in the code, or 
2.your application pool is being recycled causing you to lose you session information. check  your code, check the eventvwr for application recycle messages.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a web farm, more than one server? You might need SQL persistence of session so it spans servers. Is your application recycling for any reason between postbacks? In-memory session state will be lost. How long between postbacks? Is your session timing out (I think it defaults to 20 min)? Are you sure you're actually setting the value? Don't laugh - I've done it.

And, are you absolutely positively sure you NEED to use session state? Could view-state work?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies
It was the entry [SessionState] where i missed it in my Web.config:

Comment: <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" timeout="30"/>